# Unable to bind the codec “hdaudioc0d2”

Tags: linux, debian, kde

I've done a fresh install of Debian on my laptop (MSI MS-17F3), but when I start it I get this error:

`debian hdaudioc0d2 unable to bind the codec`

A friend of mine installed the same version and it works fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144224/ubuntu-19-04-freeze-at-loading-dell-e6430-i5-nomodeset-didnt-work-well). It could be related to your issue.